# Mysql select query special conditions

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in db: `file`, `category` and `file_to_category`.

I have category id and need to select only files that belongs only to this category.

`file_to_category` table structure is:

```
id
file_id
category_id
```

is it possible to do using only 1 query ?

Comment: One file can belong to several categories. 
I need select only files which has not other categories and belongs to current category

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select f.*
from file f
join file_to_category fc on fc.file_id = f.id
group by f.id
having count(distinct fc.category_id) = 1
and sum(fc.category_id = $your_category_id) > 0
```

Comment: One file can belong to several categories. I need select only files which has not other categories and belongs to current category Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select file.file_id, FileName,category.category_id,Category from file join file_to_category 
on File.file_id=file_to_category.file_id join 
category on category.category_id=file_to_category.category_id group by file.file_id 
having count(file.file_id)=1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/609ef/3)

Comment: One file can belong to several categories. I need select only files which has not other categories and belongs to current category Thanks